# QGIS Server - Internal Server Error at GetCapabilities reguest - no Apache error

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

Maybe the question is answered often before, but i can't find a solution which works on my system

I try to install qgis server by the tutorials by using the following links
http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial
http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/

i changed in the httpd_qgis.conf:
- LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
- SetEnv ( 3 times)
and SetHandler cgi-script

after this i copyied all dll's from c:/osgeo4w/apache/bin/ to 
 c:/osgeo4w/apps/qgis/bin/

Now the tutorials said that the GetCapabilites works, but it doesn't

i only get the error

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, admin@local.domain and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache and Firebug doesn't give any error.

Can anybody help  I use a windows 7 64 Bit?

Comment: I told you encounter the same problem that you solved this problem yet?